# Augmenting membership user creation functionality

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, triggers, asp.net-membership

As its well known that membership create user functionality lacks a lot of user details that someone might need to store. I am presenting my work around it and I need your expert opinion, ( I am using web method)

I m currently using this code (Ref Microsoft)

```
Public Function GetErrorMessage(status As MembershipCreateStatus) As String

    Select Case status
        Case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName
            Return "Username already exists. Please enter a different user name."

        Case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail
            Return "A username for that e-mail address already exists. Please enter a different e-mail address."

        Case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidPassword
            Return "The password provided is invalid. Please enter a valid password value."

        Case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidEmail
            Return "The e-mail address provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again."

        Case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidAnswer
            Return "The password retrieval answer provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again."

        Case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidQuestion
            Return "The password retrieval question provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again."

        Case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidUserName
            Return "The user name provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again."

        Case MembershipCreateStatus.ProviderError
            Return "The authentication provider Returned an error. Please verify your entry and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator."

        Case MembershipCreateStatus.UserRejected
            Return "The user creation request has been canceled. Please verify your entry and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator."

        Case Else
            Return "An unknown error occurred. Please verify your entry and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator."
    End Select
End Function

Public Function GetUsrID(UserName) As String
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT UserId FROM aspnet_Users WHERE UserName= @UserName"
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(ARTSQLDBCOM), _
        cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256).Value = UserName
        cn.Open()
        Dim val As String = String.Empty
        Dim getVal As Object = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        cn.Close()
        If Not IsNothing(getVal) Then
            val = getVal.ToString
            Return val
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Using
End Function


Public Function CreateUser_AugmentedUpdate(ByVal UserName As String, ByVal JobTitleID As String, ByVal Prfx As String, ByVal fname As String, ByVal Mname As String, ByVal Lname As String, ByVal Initial As String, _
    ByVal disname As String, ByVal UsrDOB As String, ByVal TelNum As String, ByVal UsrSignature As String, ByVal UsrImg_aURL As String, ByVal UsrImg_rURL As String)
    Try
        Dim UserID As String = GetUsrID(UserName)
        Dim SQLCmd As New SqlCommand()
        SQLCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        SQLCmd.CommandText = "aspnet_Users_CreateUser_AugmentedUpdate"
        SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = UserID.ToString
        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(JobTitleID)) Then
            SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@JobTitleID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DBNull.Value
        Else
            SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@JobTitleID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(JobTitleID)
        End If
        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Initial)) Then
            SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@Initial", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DBNull.Value
        Else
            SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@Initial", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Initial)
        End If
        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Prfx)) Then
            SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@Prfx", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DBNull.Value
        Else
            SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@Prfx", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Prfx)
        End If
        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fname)) Then
            SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@fname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DBNull.Value
        Else
            SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@fname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = fname.ToString
        End If

        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Mname)) Then
            SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@Mname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DBNull.Value
        Else
            SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@Mname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Mname.ToString
        End If
        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Lname)) Then
            SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@Lname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DBNull.Value
        Else
            SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@Lname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Lname.ToString
        End If
        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(disname)) Then
            SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@disname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DBNull.Value
        Else
            SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@disname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = disname.ToString
        End If

        Dim dateValue As Date
        If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(UsrDOB) Then
            SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@UsrDOB", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DBNull.Value
        ElseIf Date.TryParse(UsrDOB, dateValue) Then
            SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@UsrDOB", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dateValue
        Else
            SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@UsrDOB", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DBNull.Value
        End If

        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(TelNum)) Then
            SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@TelNum", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = DBNull.Value
        Else
            SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@TelNum", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = TelNum.ToString
        End If
        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(UsrSignature)) Then
            SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@UsrSignature", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DBNull.Value
        Else
            SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@UsrSignature", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = UsrSignature.ToString
        End If
        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(UsrImg_aURL)) Then
            SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@UsrImg_aURL", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DBNull.Value
        Else
            SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@UsrImg_aURL", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = UsrImg_aURL.ToString
        End If
        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(UsrImg_rURL)) Then
            SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@UsrImg_rURL", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DBNull.Value
        Else
            SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@UsrImg_rURL", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = UsrImg_rURL.ToString
        End If
        SQLCmd.Connection = ARTSQLCON
        ARTSQLCON.Open()
        SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        ARTSQLCON.Close()
        Return "User has been Created Successfully"
    Catch
        Return "Create User Phase 2 Error. Please refer to your database developer"
    End Try
End Function

<WebMethod()> _
Public Function RegNewUser(ByVal Username As String, ByVal Password As String, ByVal Email As String, ByVal JobTitleID As String, ByVal Prfx As String, ByVal fname As String, ByVal Mname As String, ByVal Lname As String, ByVal Initial As String, _
    ByVal disname As String, ByVal UsrDOB As String, ByVal TelNum As String, ByVal UsrSignature As String, ByVal UsrImg_aURL As String, ByVal UsrImg_rURL As String) As String
    Dim status As MembershipCreateStatus
    'Dim passwordQuestion As String = ""
    'Dim passwordAnswer As String = ""

    'If Membership.RequiresQuestionAndAnswer Then
    '    passwordQuestion = PasswordQuestionDDl.Text.Trim()
    '    passwordAnswer = PasswordAnswerTextbox.Text
    'End If
    Try
        Dim newUser As MembershipUser = Membership.CreateUser(Username, Password, Email, Nothing, Nothing, False, status)
        If newUser Is Nothing Then
            Return GetErrorMessage(status)

        Else
            CreateUser_AugmentedUpdate(Username, JobTitleID, Prfx, fname, Mname, Lname, Initial, _
    disname, UsrDOB, TelNum, UsrSignature, UsrImg_aURL, UsrImg_rURL)
            Return "User has been Created Successfully" + JobTitleID
        End If
    Catch
        Return "Create User Phase 1 Error. Please refer to your database developer"
    End Try


End Function
```

Now behind this code, I put a trigger on the asp users table to insert the new userID in a different table. My SQL stored procedure (aspnet_Users_CreateUser_AugmentedUpdate) run a record update on the new table,

The code works beautifully but is it a good practice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is correct, since we could not use ***Transaction*** in Membership Provider.

You will need to make sure user enters valid data before calling `Membership.CreateUser`. So I'll do some type of validations before that line.  Otherwise, you will end up with dangling data.

---

Just a minor improvement which is not related to Membership. If you pass more than 3 arguments to a method, you might want to consider using object. *You can read more at [Clean Code by Robert C. Martin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882).*

```
Public Function CreateUser_AugmentedUpdate(ByVal user As UserModel)
```

You can use ternary operator to shorten if statement.

```
SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@TelNum", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = 
   If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(TelNum), DBNull.Value, TelNum.ToString)
```